# Как обратиться к не уникальному элементу из класса?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

```
<div data-v-20aa7540="" class="answers">
    <div data-v-20aa7540="" class="answer"><div data-v-20aa7540="" class="checked-icon"><!----> 
</div>
            текст1
</div>
    <div data-v-20aa7540="" class="answer"><div data-v-20aa7540="" class="checked-icon"><!----></div>
            текст2
</div>
    <div data-v-20aa7540="" class="answer"><div data-v-20aa7540="" class="checked-icon"><!----></div>
            текст3
</div>
</div>
```

Как обратиться к какому-либо из элементов класса `answer`? У них нет `id` или других отличительных тегов.

Comment: Не знаю есть ли в Selenium поиск по селектору, но если есть, можно использовать `:nth-child()` / `:nth-of-type()`.

Comment: Если точно известен текст в элементе, то можно найти по нему.

Comment: можете обратиться к элементам класса "answer" с помощью метода document.querySelectorAll()
либо selenium через xPath